# How to skip the security checks on some routes?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

Applying following config, I'm still getting an exception from the server

> {
>       "timestamp": "2019-10-13T17:13:41.168+0000",
>       "status": 401,
>       "error": "Unauthorized",
>       "message": "Unauthorized",
>       "path": "/guests/alternate"
>   }

## Router

```
@GetMapping("/guests/alternate")
public String showAny() {
    return "alternate";
}
```

## Config

```
// For pre-auth
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackageClasses = UsersRepository.class)
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {


    @Autowired
    private CustomUserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {

        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService)
        .passwordEncoder(getPasswordEncoder());
    }


    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http.csrf().disable();
        http.authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/guests**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("**/secured/**").authenticated()
                .anyRequest().permitAll()
                .and()
                .formLogin().permitAll();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

While trying to reproduce your problem, I came across the following [AntPathMatcher](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/util/AntPathMatcher.html) documentation:

> ** matches zero or more *directories* in a path

Could you try using `.antMatchers("/guests/**").permitAll()` instead of `.antMatchers("/guests**").permitAll()`? I've added an extra slash at the end.

Comment: It doesn't work. Also, lots of posts solution are deprecated. the `ignoring()` is not avaiable any more

Comment: I think the problem is because of bean can not be autowired and the configuration is not overwriting the settings at all. Still looking for the reason why bean is not found. Spring framework has so many bombs lol. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58367603/could-not-autowire-service