# Could not autowire service

Tags: spring

The below line complaining bean not found.

> ```
> private CustomUserDetailsService userDetailsService;
> ```

I think I've done what I need to do. I add  `@ComponentScan` annotation to the bean and still not working.

Any idea and explanation ? Thanks a lot

## SecurityConfiguration.java

```
// For pre-auth
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackageClasses = UsersRepository.class)
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {


    @Autowired
    private CustomUserDetailsService userDetailsService;
    ......
}
```

## CustomUserDetailsService.java

```
@ComponentScan
@Service
public class CustomUserDetailsService implements UserDetailsService {

    @Autowired
    private UsersRepository usersRepository;


    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        Optional<Users> optionalUsers = usersRepository.findByName(username);

        optionalUsers
                .orElseThrow(() -> new UsernameNotFoundException("Username not found"));
        return optionalUsers
                .map(CustomUserDetails::new).get();
    }
}
```

## UsersRepository.java

```
public interface UsersRepository extends JpaRepository<Users, Integer> {
    Optional<Users> findByName(String username);
}
```

## Log

```
        17:00:01: Executing task 'bootRun'...

        > Task :compileJava
        > Task :processResources UP-TO-DATE
        > Task :classes

        > Task :bootRun
        2019-10-13 17:00:03.588 ERROR 69399 --- [           main] o.s.b.c.l.LoggingApplicationListener     : Cannot set level 'true' for 'org.hibernate.format_sql'
        2019-10-13 17:00:03.591 ERROR 69399 --- [           main] o.s.b.c.l.LoggingApplicationListener     : Cannot set level 'true' for 'org.hibernate.use_sql_comments'

          .   ____          _            __ _ _
         /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
        ( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
         \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
          '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
         =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
         :: Spring Boot ::        (v2.1.9.RELEASE)

    2019-10-13 17:00:03.690  INFO 69399 --- [           main] dev.house.xproj.XprojApplication         : Starting XprojApplication on missions-mbp.lan with PID 69399 (/Users/poc/    workspace/15house-java-backend/build/classes/java/main started by poc in /Users/poc/workspace/15house-java-backend)
        2019-10-13 17:00:03.691  INFO 69399 --- [           main] dev.house.xproj.XprojApplication         : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
        2019-10-13 17:00:04.272  INFO 69399 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data repositories in DEFAULT mode.
        2019-10-13 17:00:04.295  INFO 69399 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 12ms. Found 0 repository interfaces.
    2019-10-13 17:00:04.621  INFO 69399 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration' of type [org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$3e3b00fc] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (    for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
        2019-10-13 17:00:04.884  INFO 69399 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8083 (http)
        2019-10-13 17:00:04.910  INFO 69399 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
        2019-10-13 17:00:04.910  INFO 69399 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.26]
        2019-10-13 17:00:05.021  INFO 69399 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
        2019-10-13 17:00:05.021  INFO 69399 --- [           main] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 1292 ms
        2019-10-13 17:00:05.174  INFO 69399 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
        2019-10-13 17:00:05.599  INFO 69399 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
        2019-10-13 17:00:05.660  INFO 69399 --- [           main] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [
            name: default
            ...]
        2019-10-13 17:00:05.738  INFO 69399 --- [           main] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate Core {5.3.12.Final}
        2019-10-13 17:00:05.739  INFO 69399 --- [           main] org.hibernate.cfg.Environment            : HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
        2019-10-13 17:00:05.913  INFO 69399 --- [           main] o.hibernate.annotations.common.Version   : HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.0.4.Final}
        2019-10-13 17:00:06.059  INFO 69399 --- [           main] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
        2019-10-13 17:00:06.332  INFO 69399 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
        2019-10-13 17:00:06.552  INFO 69399 --- [           main] o.s.s.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor  : Initializing ExecutorService 'applicationTaskExecutor'
    2019-10-13 17:00:06.598  WARN 69399 --- [           main] aWebConfiguration$JpaWebMvcConfiguration : spring.jpa.open-in-view is enabled by default. Therefore, database queries may be     performed during view rendering. Explicitly configure spring.jpa.open-in-view to disable this warning
        2019-10-13 17:00:06.867  INFO 69399 --- [           main] .s.s.UserDetailsServiceAutoConfiguration : 

        Using generated security password: b3f078a7-2394-4323-96b0-1e54fc210699

    2019-10-13 17:00:06.985  INFO 69399 --- [           main] o.s.s.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain     : Creating filter chain: any request, [org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter@31da0434, org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter@14b31e37, org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter@7fd4e815, org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter@3b78c683, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter@11c78080, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter@62c3f556, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.ui.DefaultLoginPageGeneratingFilter@3086f480, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.ui.DefaultLogoutPageGeneratingFilter@6e24ce51, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter@60dc1a4e, org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter@5c48b72c, org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter@48cb2d73, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter@423ed3b5, org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter@20cdb152, org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter@2eda2062,     org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor@72557746]
        2019-10-13 17:00:07.077  INFO 69399 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 8083 (http) with context path ''
        2019-10-13 17:00:07.080  INFO 69399 --- [           main] dev.house.xproj.XprojApplication         : Started XprojApplication in 3.756 seconds (JVM running for 4.113)
```

Comment: Can you add the error logs?

Comment: Hi, I'm newbie to Spring world. Is this supposed to be an error? I updated the bootRun log

Comment: Move @ComponentScan to "Configuration" class.

Comment: Could you please share your project structure. Also remove the `@CompoenetScan` from the service layer, it's not needed there.

Answer (score 0):

Might be u have missed, Include @Entity in **User** bean.
look here https://www.baeldung.com/jpa-entities